# disqus not functioning

Tags: javascript, disqus

I've gone through all of the steps correctly, but am unable to get disqus functioning on my website.

my website is http://www.lookbookcookbook.com and i've used the following code:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>

    <b:includable id='main'>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var disqus_shortname = 'lookbookcookbook';
            var disqus_blogger_current_url = "<data:blog.canonicalUrl/>";
            if (!disqus_blogger_current_url.length) {
                disqus_blogger_current_url = "<data:blog.url/>";
            }
            var disqus_blogger_homepage_url = "<data:blog.homepageUrl/>";
            var disqus_blogger_canonical_homepage_url = "<data:blog.canonicalHomepageUrl/>";
        </script>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
            <style type='text/css'>
                #comments {display:none;}
            </style>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                (function() {
                    var bloggerjs = document.createElement('script');
                    bloggerjs.type = 'text/javascript';
                    bloggerjs.async = true;
                    bloggerjs.src = 'http://'+disqus_shortname+'.disqus.com/blogger_item.js';
                    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(bloggerjs);
                })();
            </script>
        </b:if>
            <style type='text/css'>
                .post-comment-link { visibility: hidden; }
            </style>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
            (function() {
                var bloggerjs = document.createElement('script');
                bloggerjs.type = 'text/javascript';
                bloggerjs.async = true;
                bloggerjs.src = 'http://'+disqus_shortname+'.disqus.com/blogger_index.js';
                (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(bloggerjs);
            })();
            </script>
    </b:includable>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT

It actually looks like you're seeing the problem that's described here: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/blogger/eBB8uKXs54w/Ljce-6Nh72cJ

We wrote up a doc on how to manually install a Blogger gadget here, and this will help you fix it: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/888340

### Original answer

This isn't loading because the variables for the tags (e.g. disqus_blogger_current_url) are being read literally instead of filling in a proper value. That means that instead of your blog URL being sent to Disqus, it's literally sending `<data:blog.canonicalUrl/>`

To fix this you'll want to make sure to enter decoded quote characters, so the whole thing would look like this:

```
<b:includable id='main'>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var disqus_shortname = &#39;lookbookcookbook&#39;;
            var disqus_blogger_current_url = &quot;<data:blog.canonicalUrl/>&quot;;
            if (!disqus_blogger_current_url.length) {
                disqus_blogger_current_url = &quot;<data:blog.url/>&quot;;
            }
            var disqus_blogger_homepage_url = &quot;<data:blog.homepageUrl/>&quot;;
            var disqus_blogger_canonical_homepage_url = &quot;<data:blog.canonicalHomepageUrl/>&quot;;
        </script>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>                        
            <style type='text/css'>
                #comments {display:none;}
            </style>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                (function() {
                    var bloggerjs = document.createElement(&#39;script&#39;);
                    bloggerjs.type = &#39;text/javascript&#39;;
                    bloggerjs.async = true;
                    bloggerjs.src = &#39;http://&#39;+disqus_shortname+&#39;.disqus.com/blogger_item.js&#39;;
                    (document.getElementsByTagName(&#39;head&#39;)[0] || document.getElementsByTagName(&#39;body&#39;)[0]).appendChild(bloggerjs);
                })();
            </script>
        </b:if>
            <style type='text/css'>
                .post-comment-link { visibility: hidden; }
            </style>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
            (function() {
                var bloggerjs = document.createElement(&#39;script&#39;);
                bloggerjs.type = &#39;text/javascript&#39;;
                bloggerjs.async = true;
                bloggerjs.src = &#39;http://&#39;+disqus_shortname+&#39;.disqus.com/blogger_index.js&#39;;
                (document.getElementsByTagName(&#39;head&#39;)[0] || document.getElementsByTagName(&#39;body&#39;)[0]).appendChild(bloggerjs);
            })();
            </script>
    </b:includable>
```

Comment: Hmm, tried entering this isntead and it wont load at all now, before I was getting an error message. I left the original installed this time to make it easier to see what's going on, just in case.

Comment: thank you so much! it works now. the disqus code that was given on that page didnt work, but i took the one from the 'install instructions for blogger' page and it worked perfectly.